# How to trigger an event on a group of elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a listener on a group of elements:

```
$('a.menu__link').on('click',function() {alert('function was triggered');});
```

One element of which is:

```
<a class="menu__link menu__link--submenu Main" id="Events" href="#">Events</a>
```

I want to manually trigger a click on the element.  Using Chrome dev tools, the event handler is:

```
a#Events.menu__link.menu__link--submenu.Main
```

However, the following code does not trigger the listener:

```
$('a#Events.menu__link.menu__link--submenu.Main').trigger('click');
```

I have tried every variation that I can think of, but I cannot find the correct reference to trigger the alert function.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $('a#Events.menu__link').trigger('click');

Comment: All you need is the ID, it's supposed to be unique

Comment: Chrome might block this in order to block pop-ups. You'd have to experiment though. I remember a similar problem that I had.

Comment: $("#Events").trigger("click")

Comment: @adeneo there shouldn't be any problem in being more specific.

Comment: All elements have unique IDs.  I did try using #Events, a#Events and every variation I could think of.

Comment: And the alert fires if you actually click the anchor

Comment: Should work just fine, and it's **not** blocked by the browser -> **https://jsfiddle.net/vhfpsg9c/**

Comment: It works when actually clicking the element, yes.

Comment: And you're triggering the click after the event handler was bound, there's no errors in the console etc.

Comment: Perhaps you're triggering the click before the click handler is actually bound to the element?

Comment: @adeneo Yes, I see that it works in your fiddle.  This is most frustrating.

Comment: @Blazemonger - The trigger is the last line before closing the body.

Comment: @adeneo - No errors in the console.

Comment: Voting to close -- I'm afraid we can't really help you if you can't reproduce the problem for us.

Comment: Seems to work just fine, maybe you need to hit CTRL-F5

Comment: @Daniel you are missing the # in the `$('Events').trigger('click');`
`$('#PastSeminars').addClass('menu__link--current');`

Comment: @itsgoingdown I am sorry, that is a typo from trying a dozen different things in the last five minutes.  I put it back, it still won't work.

Comment: @Blazemonger Yeah, I guess it is time to give up.  It does not work in any browser.  But the fiddle does work exactly as it should.  There are no errors.  I don't know what to do.  Maybe bootstrap is blocking it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encased the trigger in a $(document).ready(function()) and that fixed it.

Kudos to Blazemonger for implying that it was a timing issue.

```
<script>$(document).ready(function() {
$('#Events').trigger('click');
$('#PastSeminars').addClass('menu__link--current');
});</script></body></html>
```

The lesson?  Just because it is the last thing on the page, when in doubt, use document.ready.

Answer (score 0):

You can use instead `click` instead of `trigger` like this to trigger a click :

```
 $('#div').click();
```

Read more about click [here](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Here is a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kghnns8e/1/)

Comment: This is not a solution. [`.click()` simply calls `.trigger('click')` internally in jQuery.](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.fn.click)

Comment: Even trigger works fine : https://jsfiddle.net/kghnns8e/3/ , maybe an old version of jQuery ?

Answer (score -1):

Chrome blocks the click event from being programmatically fired. I'd come up with a new solution such as just calling the needed function wherever you need to trigger it.

You can read more about it here: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/why-does-my-onclick-event-not-fire-on-chrome

Comment: It doesn't work in any browser.  I only tried it in Chrome for the dev tools.